# How to show same <div> block many times on page?

Tags: html, css

I have

```
<div id="example">HELLO WORLD</div>
```

I need to show this  contents 25 times on the same page.

How do I achieve that, please?

Comment: client side ? use javascript, server side? use what you can run on your server, no idea? copy + paste it 25 times. What have you tried so far?

Comment: use a loop or array.map

Comment: Its client side.

Answer (score 0):

Id must be unique. Use :

```
<div id="example_1">HELLO WORLD</div>
<div id="example_2">HELLO WORLD</div>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/HTML/Attributs_universels/id

Comment: I need to write one big <div> (like 20 lines of content)

Comment: only once on page - and then just to "call" it many times in different page places

Answer (score 0):

A simple while loop will do.

```
var i = 0;
while (i < 25) {
  text += "<br><div>content</div> ";
  i++;
}
document.getElementById("example").innerHTML = text;
```

Comment: That looks good, but can I have the full code of this function please?

Comment: I mean how do I implement it?

Answer (score 0):

try like this.

```
function render(count) {
    const htmlStr = `<div id="example">HELLO WORLD</div>`
    let finalStr = '';

    for (let i=1; i<=count; i++) {
       finalStr += htmlStr
    }
    document.querySelector('body').innerHTML = finalStr;
}
```

call this function - `render(25)`

Comment: But, I need to call this method not on click, just inside of html code.. not on condition or keypress

Comment: You can call this method like this also. `<body onload="myFunction()">`

Comment: Also, as Josselin mentioned, the element's `id` should probably be incremented each time; or, a `class` should be used.

Comment: Yes, either you can use class or you can move htmlStr variable inside for loop and add index in I'd. That will make I'd unique.